# .Net always keep old data after rebuild

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, oracle

i had a problem in VB .NET
first time i get data from Oracle Database
it's fine

after i update something in Oracle Database
My apps keeps the old data before updating

i had try make the new apps, recomplie, and run the same query in oracle
its always has same result in vb 
but in oracle, the result show latest data

Note: i run using the same query

i am using this syntax to read data

```
oracle_command.ExcuteReader()
```

can anyone gave me some suggestion what must i do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should execute a `commit` after your `UPDATE`, `INSERT`, or `DELETE` operations in Oracle, so that the new data change can be recognized from the VB.NET app side.

Comment: ahhhh, its working. thanks for the help. i am realy new in oracle